# Working with Sabre web services but not by using proxy class?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, wsdl, sabre

i got sabre wsdl and tpfc connector services from sabre. also got their wsdl proxy class samples. Now these things are old, i mean their sample code is using .net framework 2.0, and proxy classes. Now its an old APPROACH, while someone suggested me app web reference which will create a .discomap , but i dont see any good reference tutorial.

So what i need to know is , a step by step guide or simple points:
1. how to add wsdl as .discomap web reference
2. how to use that added discomap and how it differs from proxy class.

recently i done some tinkering myself and added a webreference, but i still have no idea what steps i have used to add this.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To add a reference of one of Sabre's webservices you need to right click on Service Reference in your solution explorer and choose Add Service Reference. In the Add Service Reference window displayed, click on Advance locatetd at the low left side. This will display the Service Reference Settings window, click on Add Web Reference at the low left side of the window. In the URL field of the Add Web Reference window add the path where you downloaded the service files and wsdl or the online wsdl url.
Hope this information is helpful.

Comment: thanks , but its very late to answer that. i have already figured out and created my sabre gds based project long ago, thanks for your help any way.